# Subscribe to custom events in Hyperledger Sawtooth browser client app

Tags: events, hyperledger-sawtooth, jzmq

Could anybody link me to any example of a client javascript example for subscribing to custom events of Hyperledger Sawtooth, raised from a custom transaction processor? I could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

An application can react to each event and store event data for further analysis.

For [Example](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/app_developers_guide/event_subscriptions.html) :

> A state delta processor could store state data in a reporting database for analysis and processing, which provides access to state information without the delay of requesting state data from the validator.

For more GitHub examples follow these :

- The [Sawtooth Supply Chain](https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/sawtooth-supply-chain)
- The [Sawtooth Marketplace](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-marketplace) repository